# How do I find element by class name in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

What is the syntax for finding element by class name in selenium? **please be aware that I have already used the syntax:**

```
link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("BM30N")
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\David\Desktop\Selenium\Crawl.py:17: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_class_name is deprecated. Please use find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name) instead
  link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("BM30N")
```

When I use:

```
link_elements=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS,'BM30N')
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'CLASS'
```

But the above syntax works perfectly fine for ID and NAME:

```
link_elements=driver.find_elements(By.NAME,'product-item')
link_elements=driver.find_elements(By.ID,'product-item')
```

Any ideas as to what the correct syntax should be for searching by class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using `Selenium 4`.

In `Selenium4`

```
find_elements_by_class_name
```

and other `find_elements_by_**`  have been **deprecated**.

You should use `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "")` instead

So your effective code would be:

```
link_elements = find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "BM30N")
```

this should help you past the issue.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
link_elements=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS,'BM30N')
```

to

```
link_elements=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'BM30N')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java:**

```
driver.findElement(By.className("input"));
&
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='BM30N']"));
```

**Python:**

```
find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "BM30N")
&
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("BM30N")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import the "By" correctly, my VS Code only started to recognize the method after I imported it this way:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```