# automate the boring stuff - webscraping with selenium not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying my way through the book, but stuck on selenium here:

**Link to the page in the book:**
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/

**To skip forward to the part with the code that is not working for me, look for:**
"For example, open a new file editor tab and enter the following program: "

Now I realize that this code is not current as of 2023, but how would it have to look like to work? I've tried all afternoon with 2022/2023 tutorials found online, but no success. Thanks for any guidance you can give.

Per the website https://inventwithpython.com - if I use dev tools and element inspection + hover over "the recursive book of recursion", I see:

The book is only looking for " cover-thumb", I've also tried "card-img-top cover-thumb" and "card-img-top.cover-thumb"

Tried the following solutions from the web (amended to the case I'm looking for):
**selenium-python.readthedocs.io**

```py
content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'content')
elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-img-top.cover-thumb')
```

Tried this recent solution proposed on Stack overflow:
**[How do I find element by class name in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989191/how-do-i-find-element-by-class-name-in-selenium)**

```py
link_elements = find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "BM30N")
elem = find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "card-img-top cover-thumb") (also tried with a period instead of space)
```

even ChatGPT let me down - (Prompt: Tell me the python code to pull the class-name "card-img-top cover-thumb" via selenium from https://inventwithpython.com):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://inventwithpython.com")

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("card-img-top.cover-thumb")

class_name = element.get_attribute("class")
print(class_name)

driver.quit()
```

and of course looked at this too:
https://www.reddit.com/r/inventwithpython/comments/8ykq1i/automate_the_boring_stuff_with_python_corrections/

Comment: _`even ChatGPT let me down`_: Sorry for that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this way:

For Chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://inventwithpython.com")

element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "card-img-top.cover-thumb")

class_name = element.get_attribute("class")
print(class_name)
```

output:

```
card-img-top cover-thumb
```

For FireFox:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://inventwithpython.com")

element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "card-img-top.cover-thumb")

class_name = element.get_attribute("class")
print(class_name)
```

output:

```
card-img-top cover-thumb
```